# What is substitute for HighlightCentrality?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I have a graph that has determined the Betweenness Centrality value for each vertex. I want to visualize the difference in the centrality value on the graph.

Based on the documentation we can do it with `HighlightCentrality`, but I did not find the function in Wolfram Mathematica 11.3.

Is there a replacement for this function? Thanks.

reference:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BetweennessCentrality.html

Comment: `HighlightCentrality` is not a library function; it is defined in the  documentation page you linked. To use it you need to copy the code to your notebook and execute it.

Answer (score 3):

`HighlightCentrality` is defined in the very same documentation page that you are linking to. It is not a built-in function.

---

For such visualization tasks, you could also consider `IGVertexMap` and `IGEdgeMap` from [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

```
GridGraph[{10, 10}, VertexSize -> Large] // 
 IGVertexMap[ColorData["TemperatureMap"], VertexStyle -> Rescale@*BetweennessCentrality]
```

[image]

Here's how it works:

`IGVertexMap[fun, prop -> extractor, graph]` will store `fun /@ extractor[graph]` in the vertex property `prop` for each vertex (in the order given by `VertexList`).

We can also use the syntax `IGVertexMap[fun, prop -> extractor][graph]`, which makes it easy to chain calls.